# covert timezone info into datetime

Tags: c#

how do i convert the following datetime string that contains a timezone designation into a datetime type?

here's the string "2011-11-27 23:59:59 EST"

here's what i've found on msdn:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I realize here that the types don't match but just trying to
        // illustrate what i'm trying to do
        DateTime myDate = ReturnTimeOnServer("2011-11-27 23:59:59 EST");
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset ReturnTimeOnServer(string clientString)
    {
        string format = @"yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s zzz";
        TimeSpan serverOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now);

        try
        {
            DateTimeOffset clientTime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(clientString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTimeOffset serverTime = clientTime.ToOffset(serverOffset);
            return serverTime;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong in the msdn snippet?

Comment: I did modify the format variable from string format = @"M/d/yyyy H:m:s zzz";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2011-11-27 23:59:59 EST", 
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss EST", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```